# Mixed (unsafe) content delivered by vagrant in firefox

Tags: firefox

Sometimes if I open a webpage like youtube (not exclusive some others are showing the same behaviour) the firefox shows unsafe mixed content warning
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXbky.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfeXW.jpg

The url in the picture (http://work.test) is my local vagrant devenv. 
And thats where it gets strange, the websites where firefox says "mixed content ..." are not related to my devenv in any way (beside from running in the same browser). I'm not embedding stuff.

The problem seems to be only firefox related, it's normaly not happening in chrome (but firefox is my main browser so it could be coincidence).

Mostly it seem to happen after I open a website my vagrant devenv serves and navigate from there to another website like youtube or gitlab or some other sites, or a site from vagrant is or was openend in another tab before.

But since the sites a not related in any way stuff like that should not happen.

Another mentionable thing is: the mentioned file (see image) is not requested in the network tab of the developer console.

So why does this happen or whats the cause of this?
Is it realy a security issue?
How do I resolve it/prevent firefox from trying to load such files?

The title is not optimal pls provide a better title if you have an idea.

Comment: Could you please make your question more clear?
-How is using Vagrant as a dev environment related to opening a url in Firefox? Are you maybe embedding a youtube video in a site you're developing?

Comment: Do you get different behavior if you visit the same pages with other browsers?  This is more likely to be controlled by the source (the web page) than by the delivery method (the browser).  What are you putting on your `http://work.test` site, and do you always get the message there, or is it intermittent?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.